# show that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}=A_1 \setminus \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( A_1 \setminus A_n\right)\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I don't have advances, I can't understand... I need a hint please!

If $A_n \subseteq X$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$,
show that

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}=A_1 \setminus  \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} 
 \left( A_1 \setminus A_n \right)\right)\;.$$

Comment: Do you know De Moivre's identities for complementing intersections and unions?

Comment: If $x$ is element of RHS then it is element of $A_1$ and (taking e.g $n=4$) it is no element of $A_1-A_4$. What can be concluded then?

Comment: no.. is similar for complex numbers...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element chasing is easiest for this problem, as shown in Brian's answer. Alternatively this looks like a problem that could be solved through induction and a little set algebra. First let's show the result holds up to $k$.

**Base case:** $k=1$. We have $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{1}{A_n}=A_1$$ and $$ \begin{align} A_1\setminus  \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{1} \left( A_1 \setminus A_n \right)\right) &= A_1\setminus  \left( A_1 \setminus A_1 \right) \\ &= A_1\setminus  \emptyset \\ &= A_1 \end{align} $$ which means $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{k}{A_n}=A_1 \setminus  \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{k} 
 \left( A_1 \setminus A_n \right)\right)$$ for $k=1$. Now suppose the result holds for some $k \geq 1$ (**Induction Hypothesis**). Next look at the RHS and LHS when for the case of $k+1$. We can rewrite the quantities in a meaningful way. For example, $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{k+1}{A_n} = \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{k}{A_n}\right) \cap A_{k+1}$$ and by the induction hypothesis we have that $$ \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{k}{A_n}\right)  = A_1 \setminus  \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{k} 
 \left( A_1 \setminus A_n \right)\right)$$ so $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{k+1}{A_n} = A_1 \setminus  \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{k} 
 \left( A_1 \setminus A_n \right)\right) \cap A_{k+1}$$ Can you proceed from here? Show that $$A_1 \setminus  \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{k} 
 \left( A_1 \setminus A_n \right)\right) \cap A_{k+1} = A_1 \setminus  \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{k+1} 
 \left( A_1 \setminus A_n \right)\right)$$ If you can show equality in that step you'll have shown that equality holds for an arbitrary $k$, and hence must be true for all $k \in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: @ElChapo You chose my answer within like $10$ seconds of me posting it. You sure you don't want to look it over first?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You can prove it by ‘element-chasing’ to show that each side is a subset of the other. For instance, if $x\in\bigcap_{n\ge 1}A_n$, then certainly $x\in A_1$, so we need only show that $x\notin\bigcup_{n\ge 1}(A_1\setminus A_n)$ in order to conclude that $x\in A_1\setminus\bigcup_{n\ge 1}(A_1\setminus A_n)$. That means that we must show that for each $n\ge 1$, $x\notin A_1\setminus A_n$; using the hypothesis that $x\in\bigcap_{n\ge 1}A_n$, this is pretty easy.

To complete the proof, assume that $x\in A_1\setminus\bigcup_{n\ge 1}(A_1\setminus A_n)$ and show that $x\in\bigcap_{n\ge 1}A_n$. Clearly $x\in A_1$, so all that remains is to show that if $n\ge 2$, then $x\in A_n$. What we know is that $x\notin A_1\setminus A_n$; why, and how does this help?

Answer (score 1):

For those who (like me) prefer a more calculational proof style, and equivalence to mutual implication, here is an alternative 'element chasing' proof, as a very late answer.$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
%$

Letting $\;n\;$ range over the positive integers, we calculate which $\;x\;$ are in the right hand side set:
$$\calc
    x \in A_1 \setminus \bigcup_n (A_1 \setminus A_n)
\op\equiv\hint{definitions of $\;\setminus\;$, $\;\bigcup\;$, and $\;\setminus\;$}
    x \in A_1 \;\land\; \lnot \langle \exists n :: x \in A_1 \land x \not\in A_n \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{logic: assume LHS of leftmost $\;\land\;$ in its RHS; simplify}
    x \in A_1 \;\land\; \lnot \langle \exists n :: x \not\in A_n \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{logic: DeMorgan}
    x \in A_1 \;\land\; \langle \forall n :: x \in A_n \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{RHS implies LHS}
    \langle \forall n :: x \in A_n \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\bigcap\;$}
    x \in \bigcap_n A_n
\endcalc$$

By set extensionality, this proves the original statement.

$%
\endgroup
%$